# Encuentro local de SOes en CDMX - 17 de mayo del 2018

Tags: discusión, encuentros-locales

**Fecha:** 17 de Mayo de las 7pm - 9pm

**Dirección:** [Oficinas de Beek - #303 en el 3er piso](https://www.google.com/maps/place/San+Antonio+188,+Cd.+de+los+Deportes,+03710+Ciudad+de+M%C3%A9xico,+CDMX,+Mexico/@19.3845598,-99.1817381,17.84z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x85d1ff7866b452cb:0x7c0bb06b7bff4afb!8m2!3d19.3850363!4d-99.1811827)

Invitamos a todos los interesados en la informática y en en el desarrollo a participar en un encuentro informal para conocernos más y aprender sobre la comunidad de Stack Overflow en español. Tenemos espacio para un pequeño grupo de 15 solamente. ¡Aparten su lugar para no perderse de este evento local!

Tendremos aperitivos y bebidas para los invitados y daremos una presentación sobre la comunidad de desarrolladores de Stack Overflow en español. Daremos tiempo también para networking y para convivio con los asistentes.

¡No se lo pierdan!

Para [registrarse, por favor visiten este enlace en Event Brite](https://www.eventbrite.com/e/stack-overflow-en-espanol-meetup-en-cdmx-tickets-45743439860).

Recuerden que tenemos espacio limitado. ¡Aparten sus boletos ya!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para [registrarse, por favor visiten este enlace en Event Brite](https://www.eventbrite.com/e/stack-overflow-en-espanol-meetup-en-cdmx-tickets-45743439860).

Recuerden que tenemos espacio limitado. ¡Aparten sus boletos ya!

Comment: Yo pondría esta información de igual forma en el cuerpo de la pregunta, porque si existen más usuarios que pongan respuestas ésta va a quedar al final y no todos la podrán ver

Answer (score 3):

Imposible faltar, cuenta conmigo :D

Félix Esqueda

Answer (score 1):

Nos vemos allá el 17 de mayo!

- Gepser